# How to pass data from UITableViewCell to ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform, viewcontroller

I have followed multiple tutorials, and have tried many answers on here, but I cannot seem to figure out what the problem is.

Here is my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")


        let indexPath = homeTimelineTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
        let currentCell = homeTimelineTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! ProductTableViewCell

        productTitle = currentCell.productCellTitleLabel!.text

        println("The product title is \(productTitle)")


        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("timelineDetail", sender: self)

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        var titleLables: String!

        if (segue.identifier == "timelineDetail") {

            println("it works thus far!")

            let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ProductDetailViewController



            let selectedRow = homeTimelineTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row

            viewController.titleLabel?.text = productTitle


        }else {

            println("wtf is wrong with your code?!")
        }




    }
```

I do not receive any errors. However, when I go to run my app, my product title still refuses to pass to the viewcontroller.
Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this stage `viewController.titleLabel` is nil (you are using `?`, that's why there is no error)

The correct approach should be:

- add `var productTitle: String!` in ProductDetailViewController
- pass productTitle not to UILabel, but to `viewController.productTitle`
- in `viewDidLoad` of ProductDetailViewController set `viewController.titleLabel?.text = self.productTitle`

Comment: This worked! If only you knew how long I have been trying to figure this out. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The productTitle variable must be assigned from the currently selected cell in the prepareForSegue method.

Check the code below.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    var titleLables: String!

    if (segue.identifier == "timelineDetail") {

        println("it works thus far!")

        let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ProductDetailViewController

        let selectedRow = homeTimelineTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row

        let currentCell = homeTimelineTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! ProductTableViewCell

        productTitle = currentCell.productCellTitleLabel!.text

        viewController.titleLabel?.text = productTitle
    } else {
        println("wtf is wrong with your code?!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most lilely in these two lines:

```
let indexPath = homeTimelineTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
let currentCell = homeTimelineTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! ProductTableViewCell
```

First, `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` provides already the selected indexPath. There is no need for `let indexPath = ...`.

Second, don't load the cell's value (which returns nil, if the cell is visible and `tableView.visibleCells()` brings other issues), but use your data source to get the item at the selected indexPath.

In total it might look like:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // `indexPath` comes from the function parameters
    let item = model.itemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    // the 'model'-part should be the same like in `cellForRow:indexPath`
    // your mission is only to get the item at the path, not the cell

    productTitle = item.title
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("timelineDetail", sender: self)
}
```